# Label.Text only returns up to 8 characters

Tags: vb.net

So I am currently working on a typing game in VB, and it has a random character generator.

So basically, Easy level generates 4 characters; Medium generates 8; and Hard generates 16.

The two levels (Easy and Medium) works fine, but on Hard, the generator only returns back random length of characters between 6 and 8.

**What I have tried:**

**a.** I tried to stop the Timer when the generator is working, then start it after again, because I thought it would be the problem, assuming that `Timer.Tick` forces the generator to stop, but it still didn't work.

**b.** I checked what the generator returns on message boxes (the generator is a function), and it returns 16 characters like normal.

So if **b.** works normal, then I am assuming that `Label.Text` has a problem.

Generator Function:

```
''' <summary>
''' </summary>
''' <param name="n">
'''    <remarks>
'''       Number of characters to generate.
'''    </remarks>
''' </param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Function GenerateCappedChar(ByVal n As Integer) As String
    Dim result As String = ""
    ' Capital Chars
    Dim charset As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Dim cs As String = Len(charset)
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim r As New Random
    Do While count < n
        Dim pos As Integer = r.Next(1, cs)
        result &= charset(pos)
        count += 1
    Loop
    Return result
End Function
```

Label.Text part:

```
Private Sub Ent_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Ent.Click
    Type.Text = GenerateCappedChar(n) ' only returns character length in a range of 6-8
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried a breakpoint (or log) to see if the value inside .Text is the correct one? Maybe your label isn't wide enough to display the full text?

Comment: Did you think to check what the value of `n` is when you call `GenerateCappedChar`?  If what you're saying is accurate then you're passing the wrong value but there's no way for us to know what the value is.

Comment: By the way, you should be passing 0 as the first argument to `Next`.  As it stands, you'll never get the first character in `charset`.

Comment: The problem is actually in the Label's properties. The `AutoSize` property wasn't set to True.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the `AutoSize` property of my Label is set to False, causing some text to not show.

Comment: That means that must never have debugged your code.  You must ALWAYS debug your code.  If you don't know how, stop what you're doing and learn now.

Comment: I actually changed and debugged the code like several times, not knowing it's the Label's `AutoSize` property causing the problem, haha.

Comment: If you had debugged the code then you wouldn't have said *"the generator only returns back random length of characters between 6 and 8"* because you'd have seen that that wasn't the case.  Debugging is not just running the code but also setting breakpoints, stepping through the code by line and examining the state at appropriate points.  If you'd done that then you'd have seen that the `Text` of the `Label` was indeed being set to the right value.

Comment: `AutoSize` property is not written in my code. I'm changing it in the designer, so I was checking the code, while not knowing that the problem is actually in the designer.